# tailwindcss is not purged even with template paths provided

Tags: css, webpack, tailwind-css

i run `npm run build` of course in production mode but my tailwind styles are not purged

i use webpack + postcss and i filled the purge array in tailwind.config.js with my templates paths and even that i see :

```
warn - Tailwind is not purging unused styles because no template paths have been provided
warn - If you have manually configured PurgeCSS outside of Tailwind or are deliberately not removing unused styles, set `purge: false` in your Tailwind config file to silence this warning.
```

my tailwind.config.js:

```
 module.exports = {
    purge: ["public/index.html"],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

and my postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: require("tailwindcss"),
        autoprefixer: require("autoprefixer"),
    },
};
```

Comment: Could you please add your `tailwind.config.js` to the question?

Comment: i solved the problem and i think that was because of postcss.config.js plugins is an array:                            module.exports = {
                                   plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
                              };

Comment: You might want to add the solution as an answer to your own question. Might be of help to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

i solved the problem and i think that was because of postcss.config.js file.
the plugins is actually an array and not an object as you might see in some blog posts:

```
module.exports = { 
   plugins: [
       require("tailwindcss"),
       require("autoprefixer")
   ], 
};
```

or you can try this config

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  /* ... your actual config */,
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    content: [
      'components/**/*.vue',
      'layouts/**/*.vue',
      'pages/**/*.vue',
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These settings will allow you to have very optimised css bundle and remove this warning:

**Step 1:**  Add purge option in `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    content: [
      './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', 
      './modules/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', 
      './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
    ]
  },
... other 
}
```

**Step 2:** Install `cssnano` as [suggested in tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production)

[image]

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? { cssnano: {} } : {})
  }
};
```